# What technique of integration is applicable for this?

Tags: calculus

What technique should i use to integrate $$\int(4-x)^{1/4}e^{\frac{1}{2}x}dx?$$

Ive tried to use algebraic manipulation and integration by parts but it just became complicated.

Comment: There is the obvious simplification of $u = 4-x$, and then maybe $u = v^4$. But I suspect that your actual goal is to compute a *definite* integral (probably from $0$ to $4$), which opens up a wide variety of other possibilities....

Comment: have you  considered change of variables?

Comment: itnegration by parts

Comment: @Hurkyl Yes i am actually working on a definite integral from 0 to 4.

Answer (score 2):

The change of variable $x=4-2z$ yields
$$\int_0^4(4-x)^{1/4}\mathrm e^{x/2}\mathrm dx=2^{1/4}\mathrm e^2\int_0^2z^{1/4}\mathrm e^{-z}\mathrm dz=2^{1/4}\mathrm e^2\cdot\gamma(5/4,2),
$$
where $\gamma$ is the [lower incomplete gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).

Comment: Hi. That was really helpful. I didnt know the existence of the lower gamma function until i read your answer. If i may ask another (believe me, i im hoping this is my last question about gamma) question about the incomplete gamma function. Part of my solution using incomplete gamma function led to the ff. $$-2^{0.25}e^{x/2}\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^xu^{0.25-1}e^{-u}du=-2^{0.25}\frac{d}{dx}e^{x/2}\gamma(0.25,x)$$ I got stuck not knowing what i replace to the gamma expression for me to differentiate it. thanks again.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking but $(d/dx)\gamma(a,x)=x^{a-1}e^{-x}$.